# Is it possible to pass AppBar from body in Scaffold widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a `Scaffold` widget with `drawer`. The screens I need to show in `body` have different `AppBars` (some of them have indicators for `PageView`, some of them are single paged, some have logo in it).
So I do not pass any `AppBar` to my `Scaffold` but include it in widget I use in `body`. But there is no hamburger icon for drawer and it.

Is it possible to pass this `AppBar` from my `body` widget to the `Scaffold` containing it?

Or if there is a better way of widgets composition to solve this scenario I'd like to give it a try.

UPD

There is a nice way to show `BottomSheet` os `SnackBar` with

```
Scaffold.of(context)
    .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')));
```

Unfortunately it is not the case for `AppBar`.

Comment: It introduce too much of responsibilities to this screen which brakes few of SOLID principles. Whenever some behavior/appearance related to AppBar will change in some screen I will be forced to edit hosting Scaffold widget in order to handle these changes. I'm trying to delegate AppBar related stuff to screen it is related to.
I do not want to cut the corner here, so it is more architecture related question.

Comment: what specifically are you referring to in these links ? I'm not sure you understand my question correctly. Question is not about interactivity and updating UI in runtime but about where the logic for this lying. I mean that when requirements are changed I have to edit few classes. It breaks Open/Closed and Single responsibility principles.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want a global `Scaffold` that stays the same when you switch pages. In that case you have to write your own logic to make the menu button appear:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      builder: (context, child) {
        // wrap a scaffold around the Navigator so that it is the same for all pages
        return Scaffold(
          body: AppScaffold(child: child),
          drawer: Drawer(),
        );
      },
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: buildLeadingAction(context),
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// Makes it easier to access the outer scaffold with the drawer from any context
class AppScaffold extends InheritedWidget {
  const AppScaffold({Key key, @required Widget child})
      : assert(child != null),
        super(key: key, child: child);

  /// nullable
  static ScaffoldState of(BuildContext context) {
    return context
        .ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(AppScaffold)
        ?.ancestorStateOfType(const TypeMatcher<ScaffoldState>());
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(AppScaffold old) => false;
}

/// This is a simple method and not a widget
/// so that null can be returned if no AppScaffold with a drawer was found
Widget buildLeadingAction(BuildContext context) {
  final ScaffoldState appScaffold = AppScaffold.of(context);
  if (appScaffold != null && appScaffold.hasDrawer) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
      onPressed: () => appScaffold.openDrawer(),
      tooltip: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).openAppDrawerTooltip,
    );
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can also place the `Scaffold` for the drawer inside of the page, and use a `GlobalKey` to access its `ScaffoldState`.